# main-title for <app-toolbar> not working properly?

Tags: polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0, web-component, google-web-component

I'm currently using the app-layout elements (Version 0.10.4), specifically app-toolbar.

When creating a div with the "main-title" attribute tied to it, it does not "work." I'm not exactly sure, if it might be what I imported.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
```

or it could possibly be that I'm using app-toolbar wrong.

```
<body>
    <app-header-layout>
        <app-header effects="waterfall" reveals>
            <app-toolbar>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
            </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
        <main>
        </main>
    </app-header-layout>
</body>
```

All feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports look correct to me. Given that the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-toolbar) don't fully describe what `main-title` does, it's possible that you're assuming the wrong behavior for the attribute. Note that `main-title` expands the title's width across the toolbar. See the demos below.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

  <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-layout.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    app-toolbar {
      background-color: #4285f4;
      color: white;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .my-title {
      border: solid 1px red;
    }
  </style>

  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <div class="my-title" main-title>With <code>main-title</code></div>
    <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle"></paper-icon-button>
  </app-toolbar>
  
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <div class="my-title">Without <code>main-title</code></div>
    <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle"></paper-icon-button>
  </app-toolbar>
</body>
```